# MySql ORDER By rand() one row

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this php code

```
$coma_count=substr_count($Hob,',');
        if ($coma_count==0) {
            $query="SELECT * FROM user_opt WHERE Interests='$Hob' LIMIT 80";
        }else{
            $expl=explode(',',$Hob);
            for ($i=0; $i <=$coma_count; $i++) { 
                    $query.=" UNION SELECT * FROM users WHERE Interests LIKE '%{$expl[$i]}%'";      
            }
}
    $sql=$con->query($query." ORDER BY RAND()") or die($con->error);
```

Number of `$coma_count` varies from 0 to 112 and the problem is when `$coma_count` is 0 (means only country was selected) my query is going to look like this `SELECT * FROM user_opt WHERE Country='$Countr' LIMIT 80 ORDER BY RAND()` which is not accepted by SQL.What can i do?

Comment: change the code to make sure that the query **is** accepted by SQL? I'm not sure I understand exactly the question. Where is the problem...

Comment: If the question is "what is the correct syntax" - the answer is "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 80" (and not the opposite). Now you need to write the code the way it creates the correct query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `$limit` variable, set it if need be, then append it:

```
$limit = '';
$coma_count=substr_count($Hob,',');
    if ($coma_count==0) {
        $query="SELECT * FROM user_opt WHERE Interests='$Hob'";
        $limit = " LIMIT 80";
    }else{
        $expl=explode(',',$Hob);
        for ($i=0; $i <=$coma_count; $i++) { 
                $query.=" UNION SELECT * FROM users WHERE Interests LIKE '%{$expl[$i]}%'";      
        }
}
$sql=$con->query($query." ORDER BY RAND()".$limit) or die($con->error);
```

Comment: Thanks! But what was the problem then?

Comment: LIMIT has to come after ORDER BY in a SELECT statement.